# Editor for Crystal Reports Formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm looking for some simple editor to test out some formulas used in Crystal Reports.

I don't want to download the entire Crystal Reports application, I just need a small, simple application or an online editor that can parse functions Crystal Reports is using.

I just need to test a few functions used in the reports and calculate the values based on the parameters I provide.

Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can export the report to a report definition format.

3rd-party report inspection tools (see list [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#doc)) provide more powerful options such as mass inspection.